# Why does Java Swing html font rendering look so crappy?

Tags: java, html, swing, fonts

To display a complex multi-line label with multiple styling I use Swing's html rendering capabilities and end up with really crappy font rendering.

I have tried to explicitly set the font family -

```
infoLabel.setText("<html><span style='font-family:Tahoma;'>My text..
```

But compared to non-HTML text, the JLabel with HTML text always renders very ugly, looks like ant-aliasing is not happening. I tried font smooth CSS property :

```
<html><span style="font-family:Tahoma;font-smooth:always;">
```

But the rendered html by Swing still looks ugly. If I don't use html styling in setText it looks fine. I am ensuring I am using the same font family, font size etc.

What could be the issue ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing the "crappy" font. I see no problems in my tests

Comment: I posted a solution to this in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72699397/266978).

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you might have to specify the style separately like

```
"<html><style type = 'text/css'> span {font-family: Tahoma;} ...... <span>...."
```

instead of adding it directly to the span tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run your program with `-Dswing.aatext=true` flag, it will force it to use anti-aliasing.

If you need complex styling, you can use a JTextPane. Make it transparent, not editable, remove the border and it will look just like a label. You can apply different styles, it will be rendered with anti-aliasing and you won't have to deal with html, its support is not that good.