# Ugly font rendering in Swing

Tags: java, swing, fonts, gtk, look-and-feel

Is there a way to improve font rendering in Swing JTextFields? Here's what I'm getting right now:
[image]

As you can see, it looks pretty jagged. Is there a way I can improve that? I'm using the GTKLookAndFeel, just in case anyone needs to know.

(I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402797/swing-font-rendering) question, but it didn't help much.)

SSCCE:

```
public class foo extends JFrame{

  foo(){
    add(new JTextField);
    setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

I'm on Linux, so that might have something to do with it. I'm using Infinality in linux for better fonts.

Comment: From what I've read, about the only way that you might be able to achieve this right now is apply RenderingHints directly to the component when it's painted, which is really messy

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you illustrate. Also consider using the default font.

Comment: @trashgod -- I just added one.

Comment: Any more details on Infinality fonts?

Comment: Here's the command I'm using to start it: `sudo /etc/fonts/infinality/infctl.sh setstyle linux`. So I'm just using the default Linux preset.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [sscce](http://sscce.org/) below, I see the following appearance with the GTK+ L&F.

Addendum: As a workaround, you might try setting a UI delegate property, for example,

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
UIManager.put("TextField.font", tf.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
```

[image: image plain] [image: image bold]

```
import component.Laf;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18969361/230513 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513
        f.add(Laf.createToolBar(f));
        f.add(new JTextField("bla@foo.com"));
        f.add(new JPasswordField("*****"));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...Well, I'm on Ubuntu too, but I'm not on Unity. I'm using Openbox. Not because I have to, but because I like it. Openbox is probably the problem, I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure how IcedTea deals with Freetype.

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I can live with it for now.

Comment: Experimental approach suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

To get a smother text, you should enable anti-aliasing:

```
$ java -jar lib/application.jar -Dswing.aatext=true
```

Comment: I thought they stopped using this parameter somewhere better Java 5 & 6?

Comment: Surprisingly passing similar parameter to netbeans, made it render fonts perfectly, however, when I use it from command line to run my app (just like you have shown), I see no effect on my Swing UI... :(

Answer (score -2):

Using this code you can change the font and font color in a JTextArea.

We have created a JTextArea called txt. With a few simple lines of code you can change its font, color & size settings:

```
Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
txt.setFont(font);
txt.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

There are several font settings in the Font class including PLAIN, BOLD, ITALIC and 13 different colors in the Color class (listed below).

- BLACK
- BLUE
- CYAN
- DARK_GRAY
- GRAY GREEN
- LIGHT_GRAY
- MAGENTA
- ORANGE
- PINK
- RED
- WHITE
- YELLOW

Comment: Um...thanks, but I'm not really sure how this helps me. I'm looking for a way to get smoother fonts in a JTextField, not change its formatting.

Comment: The question is about antialiasing, not about setting color.